# ¿Cómo saber si mi aplicación C# se conectó correctamente a una red VPN?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Desarrollo una aplicación en C#, donde debo conectarme a una red VPN para eso escribí  algo así:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "http://192.168.200.10  userNameVpn passwordVpn");
```

Ahora lo que necesito es saber si la conexión se estableció satisfactoriamente, **¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?**

Answer (score 2):

lo logre haciendo Pin a el servidor de la red

```
private bool DoPin()
    {
        bool resultado = false;
        Ping Pings = new Ping();
        int timeout = 5000;

        if (Pings.Send(192.168.200.10, timeout).Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            resultado = true;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes usar el siguiente código en algun método que se ejecute digamos en un Timer para chequear el interfaz de red.

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface  Interface in interfaces)
    {
        if (Interface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            if ((Interface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ppp) && (Interface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback))
            {
                IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = Interface.GetIPv4Statistics();
                MessageBox.Show(Interface.Name + " "  + Interface.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString() + " " + Interface.Description);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("VPN Connection is lost!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola ...Sergio Parra Guerra Gracias ...converti tu codigo en una funcion de tipo string que me devolviera la cadena...string r = Interface.Name + " "  + Interface.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString() + " " + Interface.Description; ....pero me devuelve null